# Error while deploying WAR in Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I get below error when trying to deploy a WAR using Jenkins.

```
Started by user anoop
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Users\anoop\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest
Deploying C:\Users\anoop\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [C:\Users\anoop\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war]
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:189)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
 at 
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what is the configuration you have passed and where the tomcat running. provide those details, above details are not useful. First check whether the was file located in the above location or not.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please read [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Can show how you configured the Tomcat Deploy process in jenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the conf/tomcat-user please add the following :

```
<user username="anoop" password="yourpassword" roles="manager-script"/>
```

In Jenkins please add the following,

```
EAR/WAR file: **/*.war
context path: sample
Tomcat URL : http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: May I ask, how you guessed that solution from the given error message?

Comment: With respect to this error messages "org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy", because recently i had this issue in my personal project.

Comment: I see. Was just wondering, as the error doesn't tell us anything, be it _Access denied_ or _Host not found_. It could be literally anything that failed.

Comment: when i edit the tomact-user.xml file i am getting some issues

Comment: just recently i have edited <user username="anoop" password="yourpassword" roles="manager-script"/> like this after that my localhost is not even running i don't know the reason

Comment: @palavaianoop please read this [install Jenkins in Tomcat Apache](https://rutfin.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/how-to-install-jenkinshudson-in-tomcat-apache/)

Comment: Any solution to this?